# Fetch JSON data corresponding to drop down choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'll try and explain this as clearly as I can.

Just to point out I'm using Meteor to build my application.

Within my project I have a file structure which looks like this:

```
/imports/both/
```

Within this structure I have various .js files containing various bits of data I would like to display in my application. Each .js looks something like this:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const George = {
  "George" : {
    "Age" : 20,
    "Gender" : "Male",
    "Height" : "6ft 3in",
    "Weight" : "12.6st"
  }
}
```

Then in my main javascript file for the application I have called in the various files like so:

```
import { George } from '/imports/both/george';
```

Also in my javascript file I have this line:

```
const data = George;
console.log(data);
```

When running the application the console shows the following:

[Log of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZExp6.png)

This is great and its printing the data to the console as expected.

Now this is where I need the help!

As I have various pieces of data that I want to be displayed to the user, I have added a drop down box to my application containing the different file names to be displayed. When the user clicks on an option it should show the data associated with that option name.

```js
var SelectPerson = document.getElementById('SelectPerson');

SelectPerson.onchange = function(){
  choice = SelectPerson.value;
  
  const data = choice;
  console.log(data);
  
};
SelectPerson.onchange();
```

```html
<select name="SelectPerson" id="SelectPerson">
  <option value="George">George</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Frank">Frank</option>
  <option value="Dave">Dave</option>
</select>
```

This code shows a basic drop down which updates the console every time a new value is selected - But can anyone advise how I could make it so selecting a dropdown value will call the relevant data in from my imports folders?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: const alldata = {George: George}, then in onchange const data = alldata[choice], but i have to ask what client side framework are u using?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this very easily using a [Spacebars](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html) template.  Your client-side javascript would need an object like this:

```
const data = {
   "George" : George
   "John" : John
}
```

You can then easily create a dropdown dynamically from this data, and feed it into your view, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529405/6395388).